# Django Form Won't Save With Field Not Showing

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

In DJango 1.6 and crispy forms, I have field in a model.py called `last_modified_by`. I have a form where the user can modify the object of the model...but I don't want them to be able to modify the `last_modified_by` field. For some reason, if I don't make this field publicly visible the form/object will not save after submit. There are no errors....the page just simply refreshes since it was not successfull. If I make the `last_modified_by` publicly visible on the form, then the form saves with no issues.

Here is the shortened, condensed version of the code(I left out the other fields to make it more readable)

```
    class ModifyForm(CreateForm):
        date_completed = forms.DateTimeField(
            widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
                                              "pickTime": True}))

        class Meta:
            model = Request
            exclude = ('emails_sent',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ModifyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            #even  though this field is marked 
            #not required, this widget makes it...so:
            self.fields['date_completed'].required = False
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Fieldset(
                   ....
                ),
                FormActions(
                    Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
                )
            )

        def get_date_if_not_Set(self):
            if not self.fields['date_completed']:
                self.fields['date_completed'] = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
                self.save()

        #This is needed because a person won't be able to submit a modified form 
        #with a previous date already set
        def clean_date_due(self):
            date = self.cleaned_data['date_due']
            return date

        def set_last_modify_by(self):
            self.last_modified_by = user.pk
            self.save()
```

models.py:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    ...
    last_modified_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
             related_name='user_last_modified', default=None,
             null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the model you need to to set `last_modified_by` to be `blank=True`.  This is the equivalent of `required=False`

```
class Request(models.Model):
    ...
    last_modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='user_last_modified',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
)
```

Without `blank=True` the field is `required` and as your form does not have a visible `last_modified_by` input it is passing `None` to the model.  Which is not valid.

After you have done that you should be good to go but why not add `last_modified_by` to the forms `exclude` list.

**date_completed**

We can;t see your model but whether `date_completed` is `blank=True` or not you are then overriding it on the form by re-declaring the field.  Form fields default to required so you need to set to to `required=False`

```
class ModifyForm(CreateForm):
    date_completed = forms.DateTimeField(
        required=False,
        widget=DateTimePicker(
            options={
                "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
                "pickTime": True,
            }
        )
    )
```

Finally your `clean_date_due` just passes the value through so is not needed (in its current state, you may of course have simplified for SO)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to add `last_modified_by` to the `exclude` list. Also the function `set_last_modify_by` won't work, because `user` is undefined there.